# Zoom on user location in here map in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code for set current location in center on map

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
mapView.positionIndicator.visible = true
mapView.positionIndicator.accuracyIndicatorColor = UIColor.greenColor()
mapView.positionIndicator.accuracyIndicatorVisible = true
mapView.zoomLevel = 13.2
let currentGeoPosition=NMAPositioningManager.sharedPositioningManager().currentPosition
mapView.setGeoCenter(currentGeoPosition.coordinates, withAnimation: .Bow)
```

But I got error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
please tell me how do I get current location on center

Comment: let currentGeoPosition=NMAPositioningManager.sharedPositioningManager().currentPosition this line is creating problem

Comment: Yes this line is creating problem , so how to overcome it.

Comment: it is returning nil while getting currentposition from NMAPositioningManager.sharedPositioningManager. 
is that ok if you take your current location from corelocation?

Comment: Then how do I get current position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get current position (lat,long) by this:

```
 import CoreLocation

 let locationManger = CLLocationManager()
 locationManger.delegate = self
 locationManger.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
 locationManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 locationManger.startUpdatingLocation()

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     print (locations)
     let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
     let lat = String(locValue.latitude)
     let lang = String(locValue.longitude)
 }
```